# How can I ensure only humans can take part in voting activities

Tags: democratic, identify

Bad bots are a problem for any true digital democratic process to be successful.

How can we ascertain proof of humanity and distinguish AI/ML from real people.

Comment: Are you asking about doing this for transactions to the blockchain? Or in general?

Comment: Hey Shawn,  Whilst I mentioned voting activities, I was asking in general how we can solve these challenges where we expect only humans to partake. So the activity could be a transaction, a vote, a review submission etc etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Polkadot space, this is part of the problem Encointer (a common-good parachain on Kusama) aims to solve.

https://encointer.org/encointer-for-web3/

Quoting from the above -

"All that’s needed to prevent abuse (such as Sybil attacks) is proof of personhood, not proof of identity. That is, the community needs to know that each user is a real person, with only one account. In person, that’s easy. A person can’t be in two places at once – and a bot certainly can’t impersonate a human in the flesh."

So in Encointer, real people validate other real people and build out the network as a decentralized identity system.

Disclaimer: Not a participant in this (yet), but I find it quite interesting, even though I'm not fond of people :)

Comment: Thanks for summarizing Encointer so nicely Jaco. The following Polkadot blog actually treats the topic of democracy as one-person-one-vote in web3 specifically :
https://polkadot.network/blog/introducing-encointer-making-web3-truly-inclusive/

Comment: So can I consume this like an identity provider akin to 'User Directory Server'

Answer (score 0):

One answer is to force a captcha to be answered. For an example of something that would defeat an AI take a look at https://www.idena.io/ (they are one of the identity provers that are used by gitcoin.co). Idena give you a series of photos (unique to the current session) and you have to pick which order represents a credible story. That's out of the scope of today's AI pretty much.

It's much, much harder to defeat paid humans though without defeating your target audience if you make the puzzles hard. Consider for example people paid to be in discord to say `GM` for NFT whitelisting drops.

Comment: Yes I like this concept, but the dataset is hard to keep high quality and fresh! It needs to avoid recognition aspects and stick to logic only to stay an AI hard problem, but lazy People will bring the quality down so it needs a whole raft of complex QC to weed those out.